# How do SOAP web services work and how to use them in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

How is the  element in the Soap Envelope different from the HTTP headers?

Why are REST responses considered human readable whereas SOAP are not?

When using SOAP services in PHP with the SoapClient() class, is the basic idea that the SoapClient() class takes in a WSDL as a parameter, finds the location of the web service, constructs the SOAP envelop based on what methods and params are called on your SoapClient object, sends off the request, and returns some kind of response?

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is just an XML based protocol on top of HTTP. I don't know why it wouldn't be human readable .. it's a bit more convoluted I suppose but it's still plain/text

Form my experience with SOAP it offers a basic architecture for setting up a webservice. You call a SOAP webservice much like you'd call a regular function. You can have an arbirtary number of parameters, just make sure they serialize well over XML/HTTP.

Additionally SOAP gives you a WSDL file with is basically a description of your webservices (a list of functions and their parameters).

Comment: I just noticed a lot of sites stating an advantage of REST is that REST responses are human readable. Not sure why SOAP responses wouldn't be, unless it is because there is a lot more XML involved making it more convoluted...

Comment: REST has nothing to do with human readability. REST is a protocol design choice. REST protocols are typically very simple and HTTP (which is a REST protocol) has a plain text, line seperated implementation, I suppose that's why you could say it's human readable. And as you say, the exact meaning of a SOAP envelope is buried somewhere inside it, so it's not very easy to read.